# BIOS password and hardware clock problems

Tags: linux, boot, passwords, bios, time

I have HP 6730b lap top. I've bought it used and installed (Gentoo) linux on it. BIOS is protected with password, and guy I bought it from said "I've tweaked BIOS from Windows program, it never asked me for password". I've tried to erase password by removing the BIOS battery, but it's still there. What did get erased obviously is hw clock. This is what happens:

1. I can leave lap top in January 1980 and it works
2. I can correct system time, but boot will fail with "superblock mount time in future" from where I need to manually do fsck and continue boot
3. I can correct system time and sync it with `hwclock -w` but than it will behave as 2) *and* it will reset BIOS time to 1.1.1980 00:00
4. EDIT: I can set any time upto 1999??? I've tried with small time changes, then with bigger, then after many restarts I've figured out I can go from 1980 to 1999 directly, but If I go to 2000 from 1999 time is lost again.

So I need either a way to bypass a BIOS password (which after lot of googling seems impossible: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic134536.html ),a way to persist a clock after year 2000, or a setup that will enable hw clock in nineties, system clock in present time and a normal boot.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to install windows and use some hp tools to set new BIOS password (actually to add another BIOS administrator user with new password). Now everything works as it should...

Comment: So you can work around BIOS passwords by booting the laptop into Windows and installing HP software? Good to know if I ever need to break the "security" on one of these.

Comment: Yeah, I've felt completelly silly. Super ultra secure protected password can be bypassed in no time with a "HP ProtectTools security manager" thingie. Oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking for a Master Password or you reset the whole BIOS configuration using a jumper (at least it's possible to do so on Desktop PCs, but I don't see a reason why this shouldn't also be possible on Laptops).

**Edit:** I've found a small topic on [Techspot](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic109612.html), maybe you find a solution there. Also, it came to my mind that you could try to flash the BIOS, that *could* erase the password settings.

*But also be warned, that if the flashing fails, your motherboard can be rendered useless!*

Comment: Problem is that it apears that password is not on the bios chip, but on separate chip that isn't made to be erased in any way. I could try Instaling windows again, but it seems that "no password" regime was only for the original instalation.

Comment: @Slartibartfast: Maybe this Link does help you: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic109612.html ... also, which just came to my mind was, that you could try flashing the BIOS...maybe that would override the password (be warned that if BIOS flashing goes wrong, your motherboard will be unusable).

Comment: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic134536.html quote: "To cut a long story short ONLY way out is by replacing the motherboard". Question remains how to make the time right at least?

Answer (score 0):

You also can open up your notebook (carefull!! you´ll lose your warranty) and take out the BIOS-battery for about an hour (just to be sure). I guess, the Compaq 6730b has a little button on the mainboard. Labeled "CMOS-reset" or something. You can first try to push this button instead of removing the battery. That should reset all passwords and the whole BIOS Settings...

Comment: Removing the bios battery caused the time problem in the first place.

Comment: have you tried resetting it with the CMOS button? I´ve got problems to with a Compaq Notebook (6930p) After removing the battery, the password was still there, but pushing the CMOS button solved the problem and the BIOS was set on factory defaults.

Comment: Erroneous comment

Answer (score 0):

I take it the instructions on Page 44 of [Hp's Service manual](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02030223/c02030223.pdf) do not work?

What about some of these companies who say they can do this sort of thing (for a fee). 
Eg http://www.laptoprebirth.com or http://www.biospasswordrecovery.com/

Note, I haven't used them, so can't recommend them.

Comment: Following those instructions put me in this mess in the fist place. First link can't work because lap top doesn't provide hash (not even when F12 is pressed), and other one seems like it retrieves kind of passwords it would be erased with battery anyway.